# Issue concating two halves of a video with an image

Tags: ffmpeg, syntax-error, concatenation

I am getting this error when I try to run this code. I am new to ffmpeg so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Invalid file index 4 in filtergraph description [0:v][4:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][4:a][3:v][4:a]concat=n=4:v=2:a=1.

The goal of this code is to insert an image between two halves of a video with the image data intact an able to be pulled out.

```
ffmpeg \
-i original.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:5.48 -async 1 \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -i frames1.jpeg \
-f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 \
-i original.mp4 -ss 00:00:5.52 -t 00:00:21.12 -async 1 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][2:a][3:v][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

```
libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'original.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2018-09-11T11:07:38.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:21.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21519 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 21514 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-09-11T11:07:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
Input #1, image2, from 'frames1.jpeg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 79031 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Input #2, lavfi, from 'anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'original.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2018-09-11T11:07:38.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:21.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21519 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 21514 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-09-11T11:07:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg \
-ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:5.48 -i original.mp4  \
-loop 1 -framerate 25 -t 5 -i frames1.jpeg \
-ss 00:00:5.52 -t 00:00:21.12 -i original.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0" out.mp4
```

None of your inputs have audio, so no need to add silent audio with anullsrc. That is only needed if some sections have audio you want to keep and others have no audio (such as an image).

Note that I matched `-framerate` for `frames1.jpeg` to the frame rate of `original.mp4` and added a duration with `-t`.

In your original command you have 4 inputs, but you told the concat filter you want to use a 5th input (`[4:v]`) which does not exist. ffmpeg file index stars counting from 0:

| index # | input |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `original.mp4` |
| `1` | `frames1.jpeg` |
| `2` | `anullsrc` |
| `3` | `original.mp4` |

See the [concat filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I did as you suggested but now I am getting a different error  Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v][0:a][1:v][2:a][3:v][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 matches no streams. I also added the log

Comment: @JesseHix My assumption was incorrect before you provided the log. None of your inputs had audio so `[0:a]` and `[3:a]` didn't refer to anything resulting in the error. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help your suggestion worked. A follow up question I have though is would it be possible to pull out the inserted image with it being an exact copy of the the inserted image?

Comment: @JesseHix Not really. H.264 is typically a lossy inter-frame format, so frames are not discrete, standalone frames. Frames refer to other frames for more efficient compression. If you extract a decoded image from H.264 and save as JPEG then that is another change in the frame due to [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). Then if you try to re-insert that frame you will have to re-encode the video resulting in another generation of loss.